# Google Data Studio: Chart Calculated Field Invalid Formula

Tags: looker-studio

I'm building a report in GDS and I'm trying to take advantage of the new Chart Calculate Field.

I have the following data

```
unique_users    120,449
clicks          4,405
```

I want to calculate the CTR using this formula:

```
SUM(clicks) / SUM(unique_users)
```

I keep getting an invalid formula error which I don't understand (attached is a screenshot).

[image]

The columns I'm trying to calculate comes from a blended data, this is its definition:

**unique_user**

[image]

**clicks**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the definitions for those? I'm guessing unique_users might be aggreagated already? Count_distinct maybe?

Comment: I updated my question with the definitions.
unique_users is a column from the SpreadSheet the data is being pulled from. its not a calculated field.

Comment: Thanks Asaf, I understand. What does your blended data definition look like?

Comment: Its connected through US_Time, page_id and URL.
I think it has to do with this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119319856

Comment: @AsafNevo I'm currently having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @TobiasHerman check the bug report i posted two comments up. It explains the right way of doing this